# Has this infinite sum $\sum _{i=1}^{\infty } p^i \log (b i+a)$ any known solution?

Tags: power-series

I am wondering if exist a known solution for this kind of infinite sum

$$
\sum _{i=1}^{\infty } p^i \log (a i + b)
$$
where $p,a,b$ are real and $p\leq 1$.
...or even an approximation of the exact solution.

Comment: what does p stand fro?

Comment: @Alex p is a variable just like a,b, and i. Op doesn't need to elaborate.

Comment: If $|p|>1$ the sum diverges

Comment: I think for $|p|<1$ it should converge (comparing to integral $\int_{1}^{\infty} t^x \log x dx$)

Comment: @Alex by the ratio test is far easier to prove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assume $|p|<1$.** One may recall the [Lerch transcendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html)
given by
$$
    \Phi(p, s, \alpha) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac { p^i} {(i+\alpha)^s}.
$$ Then observing that
$$
\partial_s\left.\frac {1} {(i+\alpha)^s}\right|_{s=0}=-\left.\frac {\log (i+\alpha)} {(i+\alpha)^s}\right|_{s=0}=-\log (i+\alpha)
$$ leads readily to

> $$
> \sum _{i=1}^{\infty } p^i \log (a i + b)=-p \: \left.\partial_s\Phi\! \left(p,s,1+\frac{a}{b}\right)\right|_{s=0}+\frac{p}{1-p}\:\log b.
> $$

Comment: Thanx Olivier. Has $$ \partial_s \Phi (p,s,1+\frac{a}{b}) $$ any aproximate form?

Comment: @emanuele Yes, by integral representation of $\Phi$, you may obtain numerical approximation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to wolfram your series is quite complicated. You get this...
$${{\log(a)} \over {1-p}}-p*\Phi(p,0,b/a)$$
where the second part is the Lerch Transcendental(I've been informed this needs to be differentiated). It looks like a solution, but math has a funny way with equality. Eventually doing everything out, you just realize this function is just a circular definition.

Comment: You should differentiate $\displaystyle \Phi(p, s, \alpha)$.

Comment: @OlivierOloa This is totally out of my depth. Why differentiate? But what do I know, if you ask me, wolfram could very well be wrong on this one. All I know for sure is that this solution is not as useful as it appears.

Comment: "Why differentiate?" In order to get the factor $\log(ai+b)$ in the summand.

Comment: @OlivierOloa Oh, Ok that makes since.

Comment: wolfram show the partial derivative too on the lerch function. you should change your answer.

Comment: @emanuele nope not anything I could see, I was missing a p though.

Comment: which version of mathematica you have?

Answer (score 0):

A special case would be
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\log n}{2^n} \approx 0.507833922868438392 ,
$$
which is unknown to the [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/)